# Orchard SQL Server Database User

Tags: orchardcms

What is the minimum requirements for the database user, all the tutorials I see just use the `sa` account. I would rather not use this account, because of the security concerns.

I have deployed a dev version of the 1.10.2 branch locally, and applied the `dbowner` role to them but again I do not want to do this in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends what you want users of the application (including site administrators) to be able to do. The most privileged users in Orchard need to be able to create and alter tables (when they create new content types, install modules, run migrations, etc.), which pretty much entails `dbowner`. Also keep in mind that it's the application that's going to connect to the database as a specific db user. You won't get different db users for different app users (or even roles).

It's entirely reasonable however to want to setup a process where the app's most dangerous capabilities would be inhibited at the database level in production, and only allowed in staging, with a database deployment mechanism in-between. That especially makes sense from a dba's perspective.

That is trickier than it seems however, for most sites, since the production database is rarely a read-only business (because of comments, user-created contents, etc.). That means that this deployment process would need to be more subtle than just pushing the staging DB into prod. That's not even mentioning the complexity involved in doing this while minimizing downtime.

Another solution that I've seen used is to set-up two Orchard instances pointing to the same database, and using two different DB users with different privileges. The public one has limited permissions, and doesn't even have some of the admin modules deployed, and the admin instance is behind the firewall and has all rights and features. It's a very unusual setup however, and you'll have to weigh the risk against the practicality (after all, the main benefit of using a CMS is to enable administrators to easily change the contents of the site, so anything that goes against that reduces the benefits).

Most Orchard sites prefer to go with the `dbowner` setup, which assumes that if the app has been compromised, the DB also being compromised is not necessarily that much worse.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer, I think for the reasons you have said, it seems to be easier to allow for deployments with the `dbowner` as the Orchard User. Our plan is to have 2 instances of Orchard in production, 1. as a sandbox to allow content creators create the content and then push the approved versions to the display version. this will include them creating content types and what not.